# Does plagiarism count if 2 recommenders use the very silmilar style of writing?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, recommendation-letter, plagiarism

I am applying to a PhD program in US, and I have two referees for recommendation letters. Referee #1 is my faculty advisor, and referee #2 is a thesis advisor.

If referee #2 uses similar writing style (and content) as referee #1 (they have each other's consent) but writes only about his advising experience with my thesis, will this be classified as plagiarism?

For example, both of them started each paragraph as "I am impressed by ____'s ...." and "I believe her curiosity and background in statistics...". They also used this sentence but worded similarly: "I notice that many biostatisticians and data scientists have excellent problem solving and leadership skills. However, the combination of teamwork skills, adaptability, and critical thinking skills are crucial to the success of research projects (and its concepts), but they are often lacking in them.".

How bad will it look in front of the committee? This is for a PhD program in the same university where I am currently completing my Master's (in the U.S.).

Comment: It's obviously not "plagiarism" in any sense that matters, but if either they copy each other's letters, or you write the same letter for them to sign, then what the heck are you three doing?

Comment: You are not supposed to see the letter man

Comment: @Part-timeEngineer That depends on the country. OP's originating country may not have that tradition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not plagiarism, but a lack of diversity. For me, they are also too general.

It is also not a good practice to mention something you already showed/mentioned in other parts of the application in the recomendation letters, so it is even worse if the two recommendation letters mention the same thing.

Moreover, in my opinion, it is not a good idea to mention your professors' comments on other biostatisticians in the field that way. For some people I know, it is a minus.

Probably, it is better to mention how good you are among good statistics practitioners rather than how good you are compared to "not-so-good" statistics practitioners.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 4):

Plagiarism really isn't the issue.  If two such letters landed on my desk, I would probably think that the student had provided some sort of draft letter to both professors, who modified it to suit their needs.

The impact those letters would have is hard to tell, without the content of the rest of the student's application portfolio -- but I probably wouldn't think of those recommenders as being "highly enthusiastic" about the student.